# Can I have 2 user_loader methods in my Flask web application

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

In my web application users and workers can login and I have 2 different models for them. However, when I try to create a user_loader method for the worker model I receive and error

Here is my code

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


@login_manager.worker_loader
def load_worker(worker_id):
    return Worker.query.get(int(user_id))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fname = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    lname = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(11), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(25), unique=True, nullable=False)
    location = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    mode = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False, default='User')
    address = db.relationship('Address', backref='user_address', lazy=True)
    workorder = db.relationship('JobLog', backref='order', lazy=True)


class Worker(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fname = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    lname = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(11), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    location = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False)
    job = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False,
                            default='Insert your personal description here')
    image = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    mode = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False, default='Worker')
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    workrequest = db.relationship('JobLog', backref='request', lazy=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@login_manager.user_loader` is a decorator present in the `login_manager` class - it does not represent different types of users (i.e. `user` and `worker`) - so you'd have to refer to it as the `user_loader` in both cases.

But here's the issue - you can't know if you're supposed to retrieve a worker or a user from the user id alone. Since workers effectively are users, don't have two models - merge the common properties into a single model, and keep the worker related data in a separate model with a relationship between them (or make them nullable on the user model to keep it simpler).

You already have a field telling you if the user is a regular user or a worker, so I'd go with merging it into a single model. You can keep the reference between worker and job through the same mechanism you have today (set workorder if they're a user, set workrequest if they're a worker) or you can create a many-to-many-relationship between the JobLog and the User table instead - and use the User type to determine if they're a supervisor or a worker.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that, have a think about applying a model inheritance pattern. There is some good documentation about how to do that [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/inheritance.html). This will help to reduce your code duplication and simplify the user loading logic.

From the docs:

> When mappers are configured in an inheritance relationship, SQLAlchemy
>   has the ability to load elements polymorphically, meaning that a
>   single query can return objects of multiple types.

What this would allow, is that if your inheritance pattern was `Person -> User` and `Person -> Worker`, then your user loader could look like this:

```py
@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader(id):
    return Person.query.get(id)
```

That loader would then return any of the types in the hierarchy, depending on the type to which the id is associated.

An example pattern could look like:

```py
class Person(db.Model, UserMixin):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fname = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    lname = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(11), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(25), unique=True, nullable=False)
    location = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    mode = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False, default='User')

    type = Column(String(20))  # this is the discriminator column

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on':type,
    }

class User(Person):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'), primary_key=True)
    address = db.relationship('Address', backref='user_address', lazy=True)
    workorder = db.relationship('JobLog', backref='order', lazy=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'user'
    }

class Engineer(Person):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'), primary_key=True)
    job = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False,
                            default='Insert your personal description here')
    image = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    workrequest = db.relationship('JobLog', backref='request', lazy=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'worker'
    }
```

In that code, each model is represented by its own table that represents the difference between itself and the base person model. When you load an instance of `Person`, the query will return either a `User` or a `Worker` and behave as though it is backed by a single table.

I haven't tested the code, so if there are any errors, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and my app was throwing errors as I had two models but I figured that you can just use sessions to set the kind of user whether user or engineer . like

code in the login section

```
session['user_type'] = 'user'
login_user(user,remember=remember_me)
```

here is the code in your auth section

```
From flask import Flask, session

 @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        global record
        if 'user_type' in session:
            if session["user_type"] == "user":
                record = User.query.get(int(user_id))
            if session["user_type"] == "worker":
                record = Worker.query.get(int(user_id))
            return record
```